# Fixing ESLint-related dependency errors in Node.js Vue-based project

Tags: node.js, vue.js, eslint

I am updating a Node.js & Vue-based client/server program. It has been running fine, but needs some tweaks and recompiling on a new Heroku build. In that process, I decided to update to the latest build of everything, working through the breaking changes as needed.

In updating the versions of ESLint and the Vue-related ESLint modules, I have a series of dependency errors. I have begun to try to change from the deprecated `babel-eslint` to `@babel/eslint-parser`, which seemed to drive many of the issues. Now `eslint` itself appears to be a main cause of issues, and downgrading it to 8.0.0 or 3.0.0 doesn't solve the issues.

Here is the basic list of dependency errors:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: eslint-config-vue@2.0.2
npm ERR! Found: eslint@8.34.0
npm ERR! node_modules/eslint
npm ERR!   eslint@"^8.34.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer eslint@"^7.5.0 || ^8.0.0" from @babel/eslint-parser@7.19.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/@babel/eslint-parser
npm ERR!     dev @babel/eslint-parser@"^7.19.1" from the root project
npm ERR!   6 more (@vue/cli-plugin-eslint, eslint-webpack-plugin, ...)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer eslint@"^2.0.0 || ^3.0.0" from eslint-config-vue@2.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/eslint-config-vue
npm ERR!   dev eslint-config-vue@"^2.0.2" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: eslint@3.19.0
npm ERR! node_modules/eslint
npm ERR!   peer eslint@"^2.0.0 || ^3.0.0" from eslint-config-vue@2.0.2
npm ERR!   node_modules/eslint-config-vue
npm ERR!     dev eslint-config-vue@"^2.0.2" from the root project
```

Current `package.json` (relevant parts):

```json
{
  "name": "xxxx",
  "version": "1.2.1",
  "private": true,
  "engines": {
    "node": "18.x"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "dev": "vue-cli-service serve  --inspect --port 8050"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@okta/okta-auth-js": "^7.2.0",
    "@okta/okta-signin-widget": "^7.3.1",
    "app-root-path": "^3.1.0",
    "axios": "^1.3.3",
    "core-js": "^3.28.0",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "eslint": "^8.34.0",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "multer": "^1.4.5-lts.1",
    "tabulator-tables": "^5.4.4",
    "vue": "^3.2.47",
    "vue-router": "^4.1.6",
    "webpack": "^5.75.0",
    "winston": "^3.8.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.19.1",
    "@okta/okta-vue": "^5.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^5.0.8",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^5.0.8",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^5.0.8",
    "eslint-config-vue": "^2.0.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^9.9.0",
    "eslint-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.7.14"
  },
  "optionalDependencies": {
    "fsevents": "^2.3.2"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "rules": {},
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "@babel/eslint-parser"
    }
  },
```

For reference, this was the old `package.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "xxx",
  "version": "1.2.0",
  "private": true,
  "engines": {
    "node": "14.x"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "dev": "vue-cli-service serve  --inspect --port 8050"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@okta/okta-auth-js": "^3.1.2",
    "@okta/okta-signin-widget": "^4.1.2",
    "app-root-path": "^3.0.0",
    "axios": "^0.18.1",
    "core-js": "^3.6.4",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "eslint-loader": "^4.0.2",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "multer": "^1.4.2",
    "tabulator-tables": "^4.6.3",
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
    "vue-router": "^3.3.2",
    "webpack": "^4.43.0",
    "winston": "^3.2.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@okta/okta-vue": "^2.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^4.4.1",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^4.4.1",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^4.4.1",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint-config-vue": "^2.0.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.2.2",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11"
  },
  "optionalDependencies": {
    "fsevents": "^2.1.3"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "rules": {},
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    }
  },
```

What is really, minimally needed for linting in this project? I'd like to strip it all out, and put it what is useful for Vue and then get rid of all these dependencies.

I've tried to change outdated, deprecated modules, tried to use different modules, etc. Tried to downgrade ESLint to prior versions (the ones specifically called out in the error listing), which created other dependency issues.  Also tried `npm install --force` and `npm install --legacy-peer-deps` which did not help resolve the issues.

Comment: `eslint@"^2.0.0 || ^3.0.0" from eslint-config-vue@2.0.2` - [`eslint-config-vue`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-config-vue) hasn't been updated in six years and doesn't support ESLint past v3. Either stick with the old parser and ESLint 3, or find a different Vue config.

Comment: Just noticed Vue upgrade to v3 in the build. That's likely contributing to my woes. Researching....

Comment: @jonrsharpe - yes, looking for a guide to that. I guess that is sort of what I'm in general asking. Dropping down to eslint 3.0.0 for example created other dependency issues.

Comment: Isn't `eslint-config-vue` and it's successor `eslint-plugin-vue-libs` only for internal Vue development (not actual Vue apps)?  Do you actually require such a dependency?  For app development you should use `eslint-plugin-vue`.  It'd definitely be easier to upgrade to eslint 8+ than fix all the compatibility issues of using eslint 3.  linting is only for improving the developer experience, so I see no reason why you would need to stick with such an old version of eslint to support a lib you might not even need.

Comment: @yoduh, agree now that I'm understanding which modules go together. I'm working through the Vue2 -> Vue3/Vite upgrade, and the migration includes a guide for the novices like me on what to replace. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this with help from suggestions by @jonrsharpe and @yoduh. Bottom line, moving from vue2 to vue3/vite and removed old lint modules.

This guide showed me which ones: https://vueschool.io/articles/vuejs-tutorials/how-to-migrate-from-vue-cli-to-vite/

Had I wished to remain in vue2, I would have needed to play more with lint module types and versions to format a proper, supported lint solution.